# Error 1926 on setup created by InstallShield 2008

Tags: windows-7, installshield

I'm compiling the setup with InstallShield 2008 - Professional and I have a problem that occurred only in some Win 7 Ultimate systems.
My setup is suppose (among others) to copy files to the  "Program Files" & "System32" directories.
The problem occurred when the setup try to copy files to the "System32" directory.
The install shield raise this error message box:
"Error 1926. Could not set file security for file C:\Windows\system32\, Error: 0. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to modify the security permissions for this file. "

I run the setup "As Administrator", run it when logged on as the user administrator, and still get this error every time I ran the setup (UAC on and off).

As I wrote in the beginning this is only happens in some Windows 7 ultimate 32-bit system, on other system (xp, server 2003,vista,server 2008 including on most win 7 systems) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Which type of project you are using Basic MSI or Installscript?

I think during file copy to the System32 folder, sometimes Installer will raise exception, because maybe the file already present with higher version and that file may in use by the O.S. Make sure that if files are not present then only copy else do not.